# why is $\cap \mu_B:H^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)\to H_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n;R)$ an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have a question about the proof of the following lemma. Let $R$ be commutative ring with $1_R$

Lemma: Let $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact ball and let $\mu_B\in H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)$ be a generator. Then $$\cap \mu_B:H^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)\to H_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n;R)$$is an isomorphism.

Here denotes $H^*$ the singular cohomology, $\cap$ is the cap product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_product .

Proof: It is sufficient to consider $k=n$, otherwise both modules are trivial.

We already know that the evaluation map $$H^n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R),R)$$ $$[\xi]\mapsto (\;[\sigma ]\mapsto \xi (\sigma ) \;)$$ is surjective. Therefore there exists a $\eta\in H^n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)$ such that $\eta (\mu_B )=1$. Let $$\epsilon :H_0(X;R)\to R,\; [\sum_{\sigma}r_{\sigma}\sigma ]\mapsto \sum_{\sigma}r_{\sigma}$$be the augmentation map. It is $\epsilon(\eta\cap \mu_B)=1$, hence $ \eta\cap \mu_B$ is a generator of $H_0(\mathbb{R}^n;R)$ and $\cap\mu_B$ is an isomorphism.

My question:

I understand that the proof shows that $\cap\mu_B$ is surjective. But why should $\cap\mu_B$ be injective? Maybe one could choose an other element $\eta '\in H^n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)$ such that $\eta '(\mu_B )=1$?

I appreciate your help. Best

Comment: The kernel of $H^k(X;R) \to Hom(H_k(X),R)$ is given by an Ext-group by the universal coefficient theorem. There must be some analogous statement for relative (co)homology, although I don't know it off the top of my head. These Ext-terms should vanish because $H^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B)$ is free and $Ext^1(free,something) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier than I thought:

Per Mayer-Vietoris one can show that both $H^n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)$ and $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B;R)$ are isomorphic to $R$ as $R$-modules. Thus you have a $R$-module homomorphism $R\to Hom_R(R,R)$.

Now we know that every $R$-module homomorphism $f: R\to R$ is of the form $x\mapsto ux$ for some uniquely determined $u\in R$ (namely $u=f(1)$). This observation proves $Hom_R(R,R)\cong R$ so that we are left with a $R$-module homomorphism $R\to R$. Again it is of the form $x\mapsto ux$. Because we already know that is a surjective homomorphism, there must be some $v\in R$ with $uv=1$. By commutativity $vu=1$ also holds so that $u$ is invertible and the morphism is an iso.

No universal coefficients needed.